# Proper way to reload a UIViewController with parameters in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I was using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];` with the parameters passed to the class for `view`, but I get the error: `"Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported"`. The parameters I'm reloading the ViewController with are different than the ones I loaded the page with in the first place.

So, what's the proper way to refresh a view with parameters?

Edit: I've found a solution: call the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `[table reloadData]` methods.

Comment: put abit more code on your question

Comment: There's something wrong with what you're doing in your controller hierarchy. You shouldn't be calling viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear yourself, so that's no a good solution. You need to more information about what you're doing.

Comment: As rdlermar said, you shouldn't be calling all of those methods.. create some "updateView" method, that gets called in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. When u need to update view, just call "updateView"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;`
If you wish to push the same view controller again.